# jquery multiselect filter cannnot be selected inside dialog with modal: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the the following jquery libraries:

- jQuery v1.10.1
- jQuery UI v1.10.3
- [jquery multiselect 1.13](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)
- filter addon

When i use the multiselect filter on any select, it works just find.
When i use the multiselect filter inside the Dialog UI with property `modal:true` i cannot longer select to filter out the list - the placeholder of search, cannot be chosen.

Without the property `modal:true`, it works just fine.

I've tried to add the propery `appendTo: 'form'`, but still having issues.

Edit: sample code
http://jsfiddle.net/dQzxJ/3/

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Eddie

Comment: Code or Fiddle would help us to help you out.

Comment: "i cannot longer select to filter out the list - the placeholder of search, cannot be chosen" - I have no idea what that means.

Comment: the filter container. <input placeholder="Quick find" type="search">

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be unsolved until now. 
Bugs like [this](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/397), I've been struggling with two months ago AND one day I asked myself: What about Chosen as Alternative? http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Since I tried, satisfied I am.

Comment: A good alternative (with the identical feature-set) is the bootstrap widget: http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 1):

There is a script to address a similar issue with CKEditor in a modal dialog which can be found [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:30)

for Eric Hynds' multiselect plugin add the following code to the `_allowInteraction` function:

```
if ($(event.target).closest(".ui-multiselect-menu").length) {
    return true;
}
```